# Git and Release process

Tags: git

I have a question about release process with Git.

In our project, we are changing the SNAPSHOT versions of our artefacts with mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=XXX...

Now lets say I am on Release_2019.1 branch and in my POM I have as version 2019.1.0-SNAPSHOT now when I execute versions:set of course it will create a new version of the pom.xml and to be able to Tag that I have to commit (so first git commit -a -m "Release commit" and then git tag "Release_2019.1.1") but this will make the Version for pom also 2109.1.0-SNAPSHOT for branch Release_2019.1 but if we have to bug fix on this branch, we don't want that, we want that it stays as 2019.1.0-SNAPSHOT so a newer release from this branch can do this process again (for us it seems real hotfixes will only happens when we deliver the software to production the release process I here define is more when we deliver the software to test but we are expecting bug fixes).

I know Git Flow foresees a Tag when a release is released but would not be better here to create a new branch Release_2019.1.1 and commit the changes there instead of modifying Release_2019.1 branch?

Or could git can Tag this changes without changing Release_2019.1 branch?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy if you haven't pushed the tag to your public repo. You can overwrite a tag with `git tag -f`. If you pushed the tag then anyone that has pulled the tag has to delete and do a `remote update` or `git fetch <tag>` to get the new version.